# The logic behind the code for filtering div elements in W3School

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking for ways to filter div elements and the code on W3School popped out. But I can't understand the logic behind the addClass and removeClass function

I know that the class names are splitted so that they don't glue to each other

```
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for breakdown explanation of the code block logic here? Or am I missing something? Mind giving a reference link to where you're getting this from so we have some more context to the question? [Is it this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp)?

Comment: I'm not sure the code you've put here matches your title, this just adds class names to an element.